# Odoo filtered one2many

Tags: python, odoo

Есть модель, в которой среди прочего есть поле one2many `mes_indicator_sub_group_ids`.
Делаю запрос:`http.request.env['table.test'].sudo().search([('id', '=', int(category))]).filtered(lambda x: x.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids.ids in [5])` Ничего не находит, хотя я точно знаю, что существует mes_indicator_sub_group_ids с таким id. При этом такая конструкция отрабатывает корректно `http.request.env['table.test'].sudo().search([('id', '=', int(category))]).mapped('mes_indicator_sub_group_ids').filtered(lambda x: x.id in [5])` Вопрос, как можно использовать именно первый вариант?

Answer (score 0):

В первом варианте вы проверяете наличие списка в списке и конечно получаете False назад:

```
filtered(lambda x: x.mes_indicator_sub_group_ids.ids in [5])
```

А во втором варианте вы перебираете каждый элемент списка и проверяете его на наличие в списке:

```
mapped('mes_indicator_sub_group_ids').filtered(lambda x: x.id in [5])
```